# changing colors in plotly scatter3D

Tags: r, plotly, scatter3d

I have created the following 3d scatter plot using plotly in R.
For this I used the following code
The data setTxy, just contains the x,y,z coordinates of each marker and a value between 0-1.5 for each coordinate point (in a column with name vectorM)

```
figfactor<- plot_ly(setTxy, x=~xplot,y=~yplot*-1,z=(~zplot*-1),
             type="scatter3d",mode="markers",
             marker=list(color=~vectorM,
                     colorscale=c("rgb(244, 244, 244)","rgb(65, 65, 65)"),
                     showscale=TRUE,
                     line=list(width=2,color='DarkSlateGrey')))
        
figfactor <- figfactor %>% add_markers()
figfactor <- figfactor %>% layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'x-value [mm]'),
                                   yaxis = list(title = 'y-value [mm]'),
                                   zaxis = list(title = 'z-value [mm]')),
                      annotations = list(
                        x = 1.06,
                        y = 1.03,
                        text = 'factor',
                        xref = 'paper',
                        yref = 'paper',
                        showarrow = FALSE
                      ))
figfactor
```

[image: 3d scatterplot]

I thought I changed all colors to grey , but there is still collor in the plot.
How can I change this? Further:
-why is the scaling not in grey; and how can I create this?
-how can I outline "factor"above the scale on the right
-why do I have 'trace 0'and 'trace 1'?

How can I draw two circles in this graph, either by drawing into the graph or by using the formula of a circle?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is almost unreadable. Please edit the question and fix any missing code sections.

Comment: question is editted

Comment: Much better. Answer has been provided. :-)

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation [scatter-marker-color](https://plotly.com/r/reference/#scatter-marker-color) the problem is that the colours are given in the wrong format. Note the part marked in bold below

> Sets the colorscale. Has an effect only if in `marker.line.color`is set to a numerical array. **The colorscale must be an array containing arrays** mapping a normalized value to an rgb, rgba, hex, hsl, hsv, or named color string. At minimum, a mapping for the lowest (0) and highest (1) values are required. For example, `[[0, 'rgb(0,0,255)'], [1, 'rgb(255,0,0)']]`. To control the bounds of the colorscale in color space, use`marker.line.cmin` and `marker.line.cmax`. Alternatively, `colorscale` may be a palette name string of the following list:
>
> - Greys, YlGnBu, Greens, YlOrRd, Bluered, RdBu, Reds, Blues, Picnic, Rainbow, Portland, Jet, Hot, Blackbody, Earth, Electric, Viridis, Cividis.

In `R` an array is either created using `array` or as a `list` of lists (or list of vectors). As such we can obtain the fully gray colouring in two ways:

1. Setting `colourscale = 'Greys'`
2. Remapping your vector to a list of vectors.

Using the `mtcars` data as an example this could be done as

```
data(mtcars)
library(plotly)
plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~hp, y = ~cyl, z = ~mpg,
       type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'markers',
       marker = list(color = ~ hp,
                     # Use either a named palette in the above list:
                     #colorscale = 'Greys',
                     # Or use a list of vector scales.
                     colorscale = list(c(0, rgb(55, 55, 55, max = 255)), 
                                       c(1, rgb(244, 244, 244, max = 255))),
                     showscale = TRUE))
```

Note that the `line` argument is unnecessary unless you want specifically to add lines between points, and that the **order** of your list does matter (eg. `c(1, ...)` should always come **after** `c(0, ...)`).

Comment: Thanks, I now have the figure in Greys.

Comment: Another related question: Can I create three of these graphs and combine them to one figure (having the three graphs next to one another?

Comment: You are looking for [subplots](https://plotly.com/r/subplots/) or [facets](https://plotly.com/python/facet-plots/) (might only be available in python). Do remember to upvote and mark the answer as "answer" by clicking on the up-arrow and checkmark, to increase visibility and help others in the future finding answers to their questions. :-)